# Sprockets cache stopping changes to initializer config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, sprockets

I have a gem that I've been trying to make configurable. The goal is to have a config block in an initializers file that lets the developer customize the media_query breakpoints in the gems scss file.

My congiguration class looks like this

```
# my_gem/lib/my_gem/configuration.rb
module MyGem
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :med_pixel_width, :lrg_pixel_width

    def initialize
      @med_pixel_width = 600
      @lrg_pixel_width = 1024
    end
  end
end
```

I have created a generator that works fine `rails g my_gem`which creates the following initializer file with the cofig block

```
# config/initializers/my_gem.rb
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.med_pixel_width = 768
  config.lrg_pixel_width = 1024
end
```

And then in my gems stylesheet I catch the configuration

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/my_gem/my_style.scss.erb
@media only screen and (min-width: <%= MyGem.configuration.med_pixel_width %>px ) {
  .styles {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

After running bundle and including the gems css asset files in my test app's application.css I can see the styles in the browser being applied as expected. **AND** the configuration is working. **BUT** only on the first time the server is started. After I try to change the configuration again no changes take place.

I have discovered that sprockets being cached is the culprit. I confirmed by adding `rake tmp:clear` right above my config block and then all works whenever i restart the server I can see the changes taking place

```
# config/initializers/my_gem.rb
system `rake tmp:clear`
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.med_pixel_width = 768
  config.lrg_pixel_width = 1024
end
```

My question is **Is there some other simple solution I'm missing here? And if there's not ... is putting this `rake tmp:clear` in my initializer file bad practice? Would it potentially slow down the development environment workflow for developers using the gem?**